# How can I get more than one character from a string in c

Tags: c, string

I know that this might be sounded really easy for you but I've done a research in the internet and I didn't find what I was looking for.
I want to take from a string more than one character. For example:

```
char str1[10];  
printf("Give me a word: \n") ;
gets(str1);
```

Let's say that I'm gonna type the word: Stack. How can I get two side by side characters from this string? For example:

```
char str2[10];
```

Is there a way in order str2=tac ?

Comment: Do you know what a string is? Maybe you should read a basic tutorial for C?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with the meaning of this word. But I am a newbie in C and I can't figure out how can I get a part of it (not a single character)

Comment: Do not use `gets()` -- never, *never*, **never**, ***never***, ***NEVER*** use `gets()`.  No program using `gets()` can prevent users from abusing it.  It is no long part of the C standard.  Use `fgets()` or `getline()` instead, but remember that these include the newline in the entered string.

Comment: Then please give the definition. That should answer your question.

Comment: String is an array of characters which is terminated by NULL character. I can take one character from a  string(let's say str1[1] but how can I take str1[1],str1[2] and str1[3] in a new string
?

Comment: Isn't '`tac`' three characters rather than two? (However, that's a tangential problem.)  How do you know which character to start at?  How do you know how many characters to copy?  What if the source string finishes before the starting position? What if the source string ends before the desired number of characters is copied? Which standard library functions copy strings around?  Strings with a maximum length?  Which make sure the string is null terminated?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am not able to answer to most of your questions. That's because it was given to me a task in which  I have to find the difference between two words (gone and gosh). And it is clear that the difference is ne or sh. I've written a code and my only problem is that I can't take more than one character from this string

Comment: The first rule of writing programs is "know what you want to achieve".  If you don't know what you want to do, any program can do the job.  Your comment says you want to find the characters that are different between two strings (`gosh` and `gone`).  How are you going to report the difference; you mention that `sh` and `ne` are the difference, but how are you going to decide which to report, or where the difference occurs?  Consider longer strings too (apologies for the nonsense words): `goshenable` and `gottenability`. The `go` at the start and the `enab` in the middle match? What to return?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Honestly I don't know. However that's is my task. I am really sorry for wasting your time

Comment: You will need to go back to those who set you the task to get clarity on what you are expected to do.  You can use the questions I asked as a basis for what you ask them.  I'm honestly not sure that there's a standard answer for 'find the difference between two strings'.  For copying a subset of one string to another, you can probably use `strncpy()`, but be aware it won't null terminate the string. `void copysubstr(char *dst, char *src, size_t len) { strncpy(dst, src, len); dst[len] = '\0'; }` with invocation: `char str2[10]; char str1[] = "Stack"; copysubstr(str2, &str1[1], 3);` for `"tac"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i;
char str1[] = "Stack";
char str2[10];

for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    str2[j++] = str1[i];

str2[j] = "\0";
```

It will return "tac". You can write a simple function about this. Your function should take 2 parameters, first letter you want and last letter you want.

So in this case:

1 --> first letter you want

4 --> last letter you want

I edited my code with Jonathan's solution. If you didn't understand that solution, you can also look at this:

```
for (i = 1, j = 0; i < 4 && j < 3; i++, j++)
    str2[j] = str1[i];
```

Comment: I am propably wasting your time but if I use printf it will print these 3 characters. I don't want to print these 3 characters. I want to store them in another string

Comment: Add `int j = 0; char str2[10];` and in the loop (you'll need to add braces too), `str2[j++] = str1[i];` and after the loop `str2[j] = '\0';`.

Answer (score 0):

Start a pointer at the offset and seek through the string until you get to the null byte, storing the new string somewhere else.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I was wondering if you can give me an example because I'm not able to fully understand you.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_gets.htm

I think this is what you are looking for. :)

Comment: I doubt that. I don't want to write another word in str2. I just want to take a part of the word Stack (the part named tac) and store it to str2. That's my problem

Comment: That's a description of how to use `gets()`.  See my comment to the main question about how (not) to use `gets()` ever.  But that is completely immaterial to copying strings around after they've been entered, whether via `gets()` or `fgets()` or any other technique, which is what the question is mainly about.